# Parent Div Click Function gets called when Child Div Click is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Parent Div Click Function gets called when Child Div Click is clicked.
How to overcome this issue

I am using ASP.Net with C#

```
<div onclick="callme();">
    <a href='#' onclick="Callme2();">Hi</a>
</div>
```

When I click on anchor tag the div elements onclick also gets executed. How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That, of course, depends on the browser.

In newer browsers, call

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

on the event object.

In older IE, set

```
window.event.cancelBubble = true
```

Read abot the details at [Quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

Answer (score 6):

This is due to event bubbling.

```
<div onclick="callme();">
    <a href='#' onclick="return Callme2();">Hi</a>
</div>
```

make sure `Callme2()` returns `false` to stop the event from bubbling up.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out and it seems the inner event fires first. So the inner event could set some kind of flag. Then the outer event looks at that flag: If it is set, the outer event clears it and returns. If not, it does whatever it normally does. Not as fancy as the other answers that have been posted, but I think it would work and should be browser independent, provided all browsers fire the inner event first (which I would guess they do based on the "bubbling" discussion posted here)

Comment: Yeah, that's way too convoluted. Just stop the event propagation, which is the "proper" way to do it.